Knocking Sound when Shower Running
Noticed a knocking noise in the shower yesterday and seems to only be when hot water is going and stops when reducing temp. This morning it seems to have the same knocking but now the temps are rather drastic going from very hot to cold with even the slightest adjustment. Any ideas?

You might have an anti-scald/temperature regulating valve that has broken inside(the knocking).  They work by letting cold water mix with too hot water so it does not burn you.  Plus the water turning hot and cold just by touching the valve.

What are the risks, if any, if left untreated?

If the valve and you have your water heater set above 120F there is a good chance of burning skin.  It could also block the hot or cold water completely.  It might be doing the knocking or a cause of the knocking if it is turning the hot or cold off fast.  Knocking could weaken joints/pipes in time.

The knocking sound you are hearing is the (probably copper) hot water pipe expanding as it heats up as the hot water flows through it, allowing it to slide relative to a support clamp holding the pipe behind a wall. The knocking stops once the pipe has reached temperature equilibrium and stops expanding any more.  This causes no serious problems that you need to address, other than the annoying noise that is produced.
There is probably a clamp that looks like this that is causing the noise:

A way to fix the problem is to use a pipe clamp that looks something like this:

But this of course requires access behind the wall where the pipe resides.
The knocking sound is probably unrelated to the too-sensitive temperature adjustment you are experiencing.

What are the risks, if any, if left untreated?

None that I'm aware of, other than your spouse bugging you about it.  :)
